# Problem in C - scanf() skipping input (It is not a problem with the buffer)

Tags: c, scanf, buffer

Basically, I have to make a currency prices conversion with a menu (Im in first year) but the second scanf that executes when you select the 0) is totally skipped; after that the program prints the menu again around 5 times and then it lets you select an option again. This is the only part that is not working, the rest is fine.

You may think that the problem is that the buffer has a newline stored from the previous scanf, but that is not the case as I am making sure to clean it. Also, don't mind the strings, they are just in spanish.

Thanks for your time!

'''

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void) {

    char e = ' ';
    float le = 1.1, de = 0.9, din = 1, c1, c2;

    while (e != 's') {

        puts("\n                ================================================================");
        puts("                                      CONVERSION DE DIVISAS");
        puts("                ================================================================");

        puts("0) Introducir valores de cotizacion de monedas");
        puts("a) Convertir euros a dolares y libras");
        puts("b) Convertir dolares a euros y libras");
        puts("c) Convertir libras a euros y dolares");
        puts("s) Salir");

        printf("\nIntroduzca su eleccion: ");
        scanf(" %c", &e);
        e = tolower(e);

        fflush(stdin);

        switch (e) {

            case '0':
                printf("\nIntroduzca cuantas libras son un euro: ");
                scanf(" %9.4f ", &le);
                fflush(stdin);
                printf("Introduzca cuantos dolares son un euro: ");
                scanf(" %9.4f ", &de);
                fflush(stdin);
                break;
            default:
                printf("\nOpcion incorrecta");
                break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

'''

Comment: `fflush(stdin);` - for one, don't do that. It's neither standard nor defined behavior. Second. actually validating the input by checking the [results of `scanf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) would go *miles* toward a well-behaved, robust program.

Comment: This probably isn't your problem, but `fflush` is not defined for input streams - remove the calls to `fflush(stdin)`.

Comment: "I am making sure to clean it" Do you mean those calls to `fflush(stdin)`? In that case: you don't.

Comment: Calm down, man, I am only learning. That is what my teacher has thought me. What should I do instead?